# SQL shift all subsequent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where each row has a primary key ID (ordered ASC), which is just a number. Is there a way to insert a row between two others by first shifting all of the rows below it by one?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Are you using the ID as your sort field? Otherwise, just assign the next ID in line to the new row, and sort by the field you need, rather than change every other row in the table.

Comment: Don't do this, fix your schema.  If you can't, and you still want to do insane things like this, then change ID to increment by 100 or 1000 instead of by 1, just like we used to do with line numbers in BASIC.

Comment: I'm using the ID just for sorting, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can like you want to insert row with id 2 you can do so

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (id INT,`test` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (id,`test`)
VALUES
    (1,'val'),
    (2,'val'),
    (3,'val')
;
```

Demo table has 3 records and id 2 is already assigned now you want to add row for id 2 and increment all the ids by 1

```
update Table1 
set id =id+1
where id >1
ORDER BY id DESC;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (id,`test`)
VALUES
    (2,'my val');
```

> In update query `ORDER BY id DESC` is necessary for primary key to ignore the duplicate entry error

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 order by id
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/599e3/1)